# SQL Select earliest start DateTime and Latest end DateTime of each day

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, select

I have a table as follows for tracking employee daily entry. An employee can has multiple check in and out a day.
Is there a way to display in a way such that each record has the `EmployeeID` and respective earliest `CheckIn` and latest `CheckOut` of each day to summarize the record.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `PhyMeS_schema`.`DailyEntry` (
  `EmployeeID` VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
  `CheckIn` DATETIME NOT NULL,
  `CheckOut` DATETIME NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`EmployeeID`, `CheckIn`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_dailyEntry_EmployeeID`
    FOREIGN KEY (`EmployeeID`)
    REFERENCES `PhyMeS_schema`.`Employee` (`EmployeeID`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Comment: Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, and why they didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to do this with a simple `GROUP BY` on `EmployeeID` and `DATE(CheckIn)`, like this:

```
SELECT
    EmployeeID
,   DATE(CheckIn) AS the_date
,   MIN(CheckIn) AS min_checkin
,   MAX(CheckOut) AS max_checkout
FROM DailyEntry
GROUP BY EmployeeID, DATE(CheckIn)
```

Note: this query assumes that all checkouts happen on the same day as their corresponding check-ins. In other words, nobody is inside on midnight. If you need to deal with night shifts, the query becomes more complex:

```
SELECT EmployeeID, the_date, MIN(min_checkin), MAX(max_checkout)
FROM (
    SELECT EmployeeID, DATE(CheckIn) AS the_date, MIN(CheckIn) AS min_checkin, null as max_checkout
    FROM DailyEntry
    GROUP BY EmployeeID, DATE(CheckIn)
UNION ALL
    SELECT EmployeeID, DATE(CheckOut) AS the_date, null AS min_checkin, MAX(CheckOut) as max_checkout
    FROM DailyEntry
    GROUP BY EmployeeID, DATE(CheckOut)
) GROUP BY EmployeeID, the_date
```

Comment: Thanks. but what if some employee having night shift, the earliest check in time will have to depend on the longest interval of last checkout, say like check out now, and after like about 10 hours time then check in again. should I add statement like `Interval`?

Comment: @YOLO In case there are night shifts you need a different query. Take a look at the edit.